# Can't drag & drop files into library and users cannot download files

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I have a document library that contains about 8000 files in various folders in SharePoint Online.

Up until today, I haven't had any issues, but starting today, I can no longer drag & drop files into any of the folders. When I drag a file over the library, it says the normal "Drag the items to any location" but dropping them does nothing.

I can use "New -> Item" and upload files individually however.

Another user who needs to get the files now goes into the library and does not have a Download button on the bar at the top of the library. She only has "Delete Item" and "Move To".  That's it.

I created a new test document library in the same site, and I can drag & drop to it without a problem. Did MS roll out some restriction today?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following to troubleshoot your issue:

Try to clear the browser cache and switch to another browser to check if the issue exists.

Check what’s the permission of you and another user with this library via library settings->permissions for this document library.

Comment: Oddly it’s the same behavior in IE 11 and Chrome. Permissions are not the issue as I am a site owner (and O365 admin). I can upload files with the New button. Another oddity. Starting today, the Upload button appears when navigating to the library but disappears if I click on a folder. Use the breadcrumbs to go back to the root and Upload is missing. Refresh the browser and it’s back!

Comment: Since it's a random issue in your SharePoint Online, you can submit a service request to get more help from Microsoft support